# What is "a label for a book identifying its owner" called?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the thing - a small imprinted piece of paper - that an owner attaches inside the front of a book to mark it as his own?

Comment: Book name tag? Book name label?

Comment: This is what we've put on ours, from Chaucer's Canterbury Tales > For hym was levere have at his beddes heed > Twenty bookes, clad in blak or reed, > Of Aristotle and his philosophie, > Than robes riche, or fithele, or gay sautrie. http://www.librarius.com/canttran/genpro/genpro287-310.htm

Answer (score 25):

It’s a *book-plate*, in the OED’s definition:

> A label, usually pasted inside the front cover of a book, bearing the
>   name or crest of the owner, or other device indicating ownership,
>   position in a library, etc.

Comment: If this book should chance to roam, box its ears and send it home.

Comment: @tobyink: Do you know why I write the initials P.R.T.O. prominently somewhere on the book-plate page? They stand for Please Return To Owner!!

Answer (score 18):

As wikipedia says -

> A bookplate, also known as ex-librīs [Latin, "from the books of..."],
>   is usually a small print or decorative label pasted into a book, often
>   on the inside front cover, to indicate its owner. Simple typographical
>   bookplates are termed "booklabels".

Also, In the United States, bookplates replaced book rhymes after the 19th century.

Comment: YES! Bookplate was the word I couldn't remember. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 13):

It is an "Ex Libris" **bookplate** (or stamp), usually placed on the inside of the front, whereupon one writes one's name as owner of the book (or orders them pre-printed with one's name).

This is a popular one in the US.

[image]